# How do you figure out the popularity of different search terms in Bing?

Tags: search, bing

[Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends) lets you view the relative popularity of search terms, is there a similar service for Bing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bing <strike>has</strike> used to have a similar service: [**Bing XRank**](http://www.bing.com/xrank)

Unfortunately, as of October 2010, [Bing XRank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bing_xRank) has been shut down.

Comment: Now "http://www.bing.com/xrank" page doesn't exist. It seems this service is no more available or changed to some other service.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Thanks for the feedback.